# JTable multiple selection on Mac OS X

Tags: java, macos, swing, jtable

I have a Swing application and we are having a problem with some Mac users and `JTable` components.

The tables have this selection mode set:

```
setSelectionMode(javax.swing.ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
```

On Windows with this selected you can:

1. select a single row
2. select contiguous rows by holding the mouse and dragging
3. select contiguous rows by clicking the first row to select, pressing shift and clicking the end row to select
4. Select multiple groups of contiguous rows by clicking a row and drag and then holding ctrl and doing it again from a different row
5. You can hold Ctrl down and individually select rows that are Not contiguous

On Mac OS you can only do 1 and 2.
I don't care about 3 and 4, but I really need them to be able to select random rows that are not contiguous.

This is a picture of the selection behavior described in #5 which doesn't work on Mac:
[image: non-contiguous JTable selection]

I generated this on windows using the standard JTable simple demo.  You can't do so on Mac.  You can on linux.  Here is the link to that demo:
[docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)

Is this a known problem or is there a solution known?

Comment: This is easily reproducible even from the standard jtable demo. 
 Just launch the jnlp simple table demo on a mac and you can't selet non contiguous rows. 
              https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html

Comment: I did verify that this is not a problem in Linux.  So Mac only.

Comment: I guess this is happening because you aren’t using the platform look and feel. Did you try both control and command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Windows Ctrl key is closer in function to Mac's Command key, not the Control key, despite Java recognizing Win's Ctrl key & Mac's Control key as having the same KeyEvent#getKeyCode() value of 17.

Selecting non-contiguous rows worked for me by holding down the Command key, not Control.  Tested on a MacBook Air with an M1 chip running MacOS Monterey 12.0.1, using Azul Zulu's Build of the OpenJDK version 17.0.2.

Comment: Thank you.  I tried Azul, but I might be limited as I can't do 17 because of backward compatibility requirements.  I tried v11 and v8 and it doesn't work.  Any chance you could test with with an older version?

Comment: No problem, unfortunate that it didn't work.  I can confirm Azul v11 can do it on my machine.

Comment: Well I have tried Azul 11 with my application and it doesn't allow multiple selection.  I can not test with the jnlp SimpleDemo because that doesn't work with Azul.  I can do multiple non-contiguous selection on the test machine outside of java applications.  So I must be missing something?

Comment: It sounds like you might need a custom implementation.  I wrote up an example of how to track (not display) non-contiguous selected rows (prints to console): https://gist.github.com/woodrow73/f279f229990402f079e39035da9f9b55

As for hooking up the display, I'm not sure how.

Comment: I think you are right or something with my implementation is limiting.  But most of our users are on a different version of java.  I hate the idea of a custom implementation but you might be right.  Thanks for your efforts to help me, I really appreciate it.

Comment: You're welcome,  also I updated the code to use `MouseEvent#isControlDown()`, so that even if the window is out of focus, it'll keep track of the key's state.